# Django error when I run ./manage syncdb

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtualenv, optparse, syncdb

I'm new at Django , and I got an existent  project and I need to runserver , I activated virtual env
and install all the requirements from the file "requirements.txt" ane then
 i try to **syncdb** and i got this error: (all the requirements is installed well )

(venv)➜  gates git:(master) ✗  ./manageweb.py syncdb

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manageweb.py", line 12, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/almog/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py",
line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/almog/django-trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py",
line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/almog/django-trunk/django/core/management/base.py",
line 378, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
  File "/Users/almog/django-trunk/django/core/management/base.py",
line 327, in create_parser
    parser.add_option(opt)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/optparse.py",
line 1021, in add_option
    self._check_conflict(option)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/optparse.py",
line 996, in _check_conflict
    option)
optparse.OptionConflictError: option --verbosity: conflicting option
string(s): --verbosity
```

- I work on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: Are you running Django trunk? Try using a stable released version.

Comment: Yes u right , but the venv is  installing another Django version, so its matter?

Comment: It does seem to cause a problem because in the traceback I see `django-trunk` everywhere, not Django 1.6, 1.7 or what you have installed. You should be using / running the Django version that's installed, the trunk can be unstable. Can you try removing the virtualenv, recreating it again and installing only the stable Django version?